# Question about set window full screen with SetWindowPos

Tags: c++, window, setwindowpos

In my app, I want to keep my window full screen. So I added resizing window function when received WM_DISPLAYCHANGE event.
In the resizing window function, I use EnumDisplayMonitors to get current size of monitor, the size is correct. Then I use SetWindowPos function to set my window size equal to the monitor. But after SetWindowPos called, I found my window is still a little smaller than the monitor size some time. It seems that the desktop is not ready enough. I also set SWP_NOSENDCHANGING flag in the SetWindowPos function but still not work.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to make a window full screen is not by reacting dynamically to `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` or query the display dimensions. The canonical way to make a window full screen is to set its style to `WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE` its extended style to `WS_EX_TOPMOST` using *SetWindowLong*, followed by a call to  *SetWindowPos* with flag `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`, then maximize it with *ShowWindow`with flags`SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`.

Comment: Does this way can keep the window full screen when I change the display resolution? Could you please show the code?